# How to name different components in adapter pattern?

Tags: java, php, naming, naming-standards, adapter

(example code in PHP, but this can apply to more languages)

I have a scenario with an adapter pattern, where I have classes, interfaces and objects with different roles, like so:

1. An original object implementing `CatInterface`.
2. A class that implements `DogInterface`, which wraps a `CatInterface` object.
3. An instance of that class, wrapping the `$cat` object.
4. A service object, that wraps cat objects into new adapter instances.

My question: In this scenario, which component is the "adapter"?

E.g. the service object might look like this:

```
class CatDogAdapter {
  function adapt(CatInterface $cat) : DogInterface {
    return new DogFromCat($cat);
  }
}

$adapter = new CatDogAdapter();
$cat = new Cat;
$dog = $adapter->adapt($cat);
```

In this example, I used the term "adapter" in the name of the service object / class. But is this the common way that the name is used? Or should I rather use the term "adapter" for the "DogFromCat" class, and name the service e.g. "AdapterFinder" or "AdapterFactory"?

Ideal would be literature or examples that point to a common practice in naming these components.

Maybe such a consensus does not exist, and it is all the wild west - in this case the question goes nowhere, and I have to decide for myself.

I am tagging this as PHP and Java, because I think the question would apply to both languages.

### EDIT: Why have an adapter factory?

The answer I got so far suggests that the example might be too trivial.

My actual use case is something like this:

```
// Maybe $adapter should rather be named $adapterFactory?
$dogFromCat = $adapter->adapt($cat, DogInterface::class);
```

There is some mapping logic that determines which adapter class to use depending on the desired return type and the type of the to-be-adapted object.

But even with the simpler example that only builds DogFromCat objects, there can be reasons to have such an adapter factory object:

- It can be passed around as a dependency to other components.
- It can contain dependencies to be injected into the DogFromCat in addition to the $cat object.
- It can behave differently for different sub-types of cat.

As the text of this edit suggests, the best way to name this might be "AdapterFactory". So maybe I answered my question myself this way.

Comment: People, can you explain why you are voting this down?

Comment: Probably [bad experiences of naming requests](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6582/on-the-troubles-of-naming-and-terminology)

Comment: @Caleth I looked at this before. I think my question is within the range of acceptable questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `DogFromCat` class is an instance of the *Object Adapter Pattern* as defined in the *Design Patterns* book. Its name is fine, alternatively it could have been called a `CatToDogAdapter`.

Your `CatDogAdapter` class is some kind of factory that creates such an adapter. Very likely it can be eliminated from your design without any drawbacks. You can just call the adapter constructor directly. The only reason to keep this factory would be if you had different adapter implementations and would need to select them at runtime, e.g. for dependency injection. But that would be unusual.

Comment: "The only reason to keep this factory would be if you had different adapter implementations and would need to select them at runtime, e.g. for dependency injection. But that would be unusual." - this is exactly what I am doing. The factory thingy is the reason why I asked the question. Maybe I should make the example less trivial.